# Loop through custom control classes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

I would like to use a function at startup to apply several properties to a custom control class.

```
Public Shared Function ToggleSwitchProperties()
    Form1.ToggleSwitch1.OnText = "ON"
    Form1.ToggleSwitch1.OnFont = New Font(Form1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    Form1.ToggleSwitch1.OnForeColor = Color.White
    Form1.ToggleSwitch1.OffText = "OFF"
    Form1.ToggleSwitch1.OffFont = New Font(Form1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    Form1.ToggleSwitch1.OffForeColor = Color.White
End Function
```

This is what I have so far. I would like to apply these settings to 5 other toggle switches (named `ToggleSwitch1` to `ToggleSwitch5`) but, for some reason, I can't find a solution.
Some more information about the situation:

I created a Form with a TabControl on it and the switches are located on `TabPage1`.
The toggle switches are custom made (**`JCS.ToggleSwitch`** from CodeProject)

Comment: Normally you'd change these properties in design-mode with the Properties window.  But you haven't explained why that's hard to do.  Next usual hangup is that vb.net programmers are uncomfortable about writing a constructor, Sub New.  Next usual hangup is recognizing that this method needs a parameter of type ToggleSwitch.

Comment: pretty simple: Of course I could use the design-mode but I would like to understand how this could work in case I face another problem in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your controls in a single array and iterate this temporary collection to set the properties af all the controls referenced.  You can *call* these controls by name even if they're not direct child of the Parent Form (they are child of another container, a TabPage of a TabControl, in this case).

Note that you're using a `Function` that doesn't return a value, which makes it a `Sub` instead.
A `static` (`Shared`) method doesn't seem appropriate to reference instances of controls.
See also whether this method needs to be `Public`. Probaly not.
Let's make it `internal` (`Friend`) and see if it's ok.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ToggleSwitchProperties()
End Sub

Friend Sub ToggleSwitchProperties()
    For Each tSwitch As ToggleSwitch In {ToggleSwitch1, ToggleSwitch2, ToggleSwitch3, ToggleSwitch4, ToggleSwitch5}
        tSwitch.OnText = "ON"
        tSwitch.OnFont = New Font(Form1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
        tSwitch.OnForeColor = Color.White
        tSwitch.OffText = "OFF"
        '(... all other settings ...)
    Next
End Function
```

---

Option 2.
You could also use a recursive method that searches and sets the properties of all the controls of a specific type, which are inside a container or any of its sub-containers (a `TabPage` inside a `TabControl`, in this case).
In this case, you don't need to specify all the names of the controls affected: the method will modifiy all the controls it finds inside the specified container.

In your case, you could call this method using the **`TabControl`** that contain your **`ToggleSwitch`** control as argument:

**EDIT**:
The code was missing a cast: **`Dim tSwitch = DirectCast(ctl, ToggleSwitch)`**, which prevents the code from working as expected. Now added back.

```
ToggleSwitchProperties(TabControl1)
```

```
Friend Sub ToggleSwitchProperties(ctlParent As Control)

    If (ctlParent Is Nothing) OrElse (Not ctlParent.HasChildren) Then Return
    For Each ctl As Control In ctlParent.Controls.OfType(Of Control)
        If TypeOf ctl Is ToggleSwitch Then
            Dim tSwitch = DirectCast(ctl, ToggleSwitch)
            tSwitch.OnText = "ON"
            tSwitch.OnFont = New Font(Form1.Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold)
            '(... all other settings ...)
        Else
            If ctl.HasChildren Then
                ToggleSwitchProperties(ctl)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Look, in pasting the code, by mistake I left out the cast of Control to ToggleSwitch: `Dim switch = DirectCast(ctl, ToggleSwitch)`, which will prevent the code from working as intended. Sorry for that. See the Edit. Use the updated code.